# Is it good practice to create an index on embedded document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, embedded-documents

Is it good practice to create an index on an embedded document? How does this relate to performance? Is there a noticeable real performance impact compared to a reference?

Comment: Do you have a sample? Did you run any tests?

Comment: You can create an index on any type of field in your document - an embedded document or its individual fields are no exception. It depends upon your use case. MongoDB has array and sub-documents as composite types.